# Use Variable from Another Function in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to take the return value from the function on the top and then do something with it in the function on the bottom. What should I put in the bottom function to use the value that was returned from "loadVectorWithReturn"

I do realize that I could create a new variable and store it there for later recall but I am trying to do more complicated things now.

Thank you

```
double vectors1::loadVectorWithReturn() {
    vectors1 v1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        v1.value.push_back(i);
        cout << v1.value[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << v1.value[5] << endl;
    return v1.value[5];
}

double doSomethingWithVectorReturn(TAKE IN VALUE FROM loadVectorWithReturn) {
    //do something with v1.value[5];
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just call `loadVectorWithReturn()` and not need to pass in any arguments?

Comment: You want to avoid the use of another variable? Why? It can be done, but the resultant close will be harder to read than if you used another variable.

Comment: When I put loadVectorWithReturn() into the doSomethingWithVectorReturn function I get a identifier is unidentified.

Comment: doSomethingWithVectorReturn is not part of the vectors1 class so you need to put "vectors1::" in front of it aswell.

Comment: @Elipzer: Notice that `loadVectorWithReturn()` is not (yet) a static method, so `doSomethingWithVectorReturn` will need an instance of `vectors1`. There is more than one way to do this, but it is not yet clear what the goal is, other than deliberately doing things the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying, "I don't want to make a global variable for v1", you could do this.

```
double vectors1::loadVectorWithReturn() {
    vectors1 v1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        v1.value.push_back(i);
        cout << v1.value[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << v1.value[5] << endl;
    return v1.value[5];
}

double vectors1::doSomethingWithVectorReturn() {
    int returned = loadVectorWithReturn();
    //Do something with returned.
}
```

**Note: the "vectors1::" in front of "doSomethingWithVectorReturn" allows "doSomethingWithVectorReturn" to use the "loadVectorWithReturn" function.**

Keep in mind that if you are only using the "returned" value one time (or multiple although that can be slower in many cases), you could skip setting the variable and just use "loadVectorWithReturn()" in place of it.

Example (Simply cout's the value):

```
double vectors1::doSomethingWithVectorReturn() {
    cout << loadVectorWithReturn();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Elipzer I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am feeling like you are needing this because you will use  loadVectorWithReturnlater  within doSomethingWithVectorReturn in some point.

If this is the situation we can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

 struct A
 {
     int fooA() const
     {
         return 5;
     }
 };

 void doSomethingWithA( std::function<int()> foo )
 {
     std::cout << foo();
 }

int main()
{
    A a;
    doSomethingWithA([a]()
    {
        return a.fooA();
    });
}
```